# How to debounce search suggestions in flutter's SearchPage Widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to have Google Places search suggestions using the default flutter's **SearchPage**, whenever the user starts typing I need to give autocomplete suggestions and I achieve this Asynchronously using `FutureBuilder`, the problem now is that I need to debounce the dispatch of search requests for 500ms or more rather than wasting a lot of requests while the user is still typing

To summarize what I've done so far:

1) In my widget I call

```
showSearch(context: context, delegate: _delegate);
```

2) My delegate looks like this:

```
class _LocationSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate<Suggestion> {   
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        tooltip: 'Clear',
        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
          showSuggestions(context);
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) => IconButton(
        tooltip: 'Back',
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
          progress: transitionAnimation,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        },
      );

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Suggestion>>(
      future: GooglePlaces.getInstance().getAutocompleteSuggestions(query),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Suggestion>> suggestions) {
        if (!suggestions.hasData) {
          return Text('No results');
        }
        return buildLocationSuggestions(suggestions.data);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return buildResults(context);
  }

  Widget buildLocationSuggestions(List<Suggestion> suggestions) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
            title: Text(suggestions[index].text),
            onTap: () {
              showResults(context);
            },
          ),
      itemCount: suggestions.length,
    );
  }
}
```

3-I need to throttle / debounce searching until xxx Milliseconds have passed

I have 1 idea in mind, would there be an easy way to convert FutureBuilder to Stream and Use Stream builder, (which I read in some articles that it supports debouncing)?

**I am aware that there are some 3rd party AutoComplete widgets like `TypeAhead` that's doing that (from scratch) but I don't wanna use this at the moment.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I want to achieve the same above functionality but is not able to do ..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update:** I made a package for this that works with callbacks, futures, and/or streams. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/debounce_throttle. Using it would simplify both of the approaches described below, especially the stream based approach as no new classes would need to be introduced. Here's a dartpad example https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e4e9c07dc320ec400a59827fff66bb49.

There are at least two ways of doing this, a `Future` based approach, and a `Stream` based approach. Similar questions have gotten pointed towards using Streams since debouncing is built in, but let's look at both methods.

**Future-based approach**

`Future`s themselves aren't cancelable, but the underlying `Timer`s they use are. Here's a simple class that implements basic debounce functionality, using a callback instead of a Future.

```
class Debouncer<T> {
  Debouncer(this.duration, this.onValue);
  final Duration duration;
  void Function(T value) onValue;
  T _value;
  Timer _timer;
  T get value => _value;
  set value(T val) {
    _value = val;
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(duration, () => onValue(_value));
  }  
}
```

Then to use it (DartPad compatible):

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {      
  final debouncer = Debouncer<String>(Duration(milliseconds: 250), print);
  debouncer.value = '';
  final timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 200), (_) {
    debouncer.value += 'x';
  });
  /// prints "xxxxx" after 1250ms.
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000)).then((_) => timer.cancel()); 
}
```

Now to turn the callback into a Future, use a `Completer`. Here's an example that debounces the `List<Suggestion>` call to Google's API.

```
void main() {
  final completer = Completer<List<Suggestion>>();  
  final debouncer = Debouncer<String>(Duration(milliseconds: 250), (value) async {        
    completer.complete(await GooglePlaces.getInstance().getAutocompleteSuggestions(value));
  });           

  /// Using with a FutureBuilder.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Suggestion>>(
      future: completer.future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Stream-based approach**

Since the data in question arrives from a Future and not a Stream, we have to setup a class to handle query inputs and suggestion outputs. Luckily it handles debouncing the input stream naturally.

```
class SuggestionsController {
  SuggestionsController(this.duration) {
    _queryController.stream
        .transform(DebounceStreamTransformer(duration))
        .listen((query) async {
      _suggestions.add(
          await GooglePlaces.getInstance().getAutocompleteSuggestions(query));
    });
  }    

  final Duration duration;
  final _queryController = StreamController<String>();
  final _suggestions = BehaviorSubject<List<Suggestion>>();

  Sink<String> get query => _queryController.sink;
  Stream<List<Suggestion>> get suggestions => _suggestions.stream;

  void dispose() {
    _queryController.close();
    _suggestions.close();
  }
}
```

To use this controller class in Flutter, let's create a StatefulWidget that will manage the controller's state. This part includes the call to your function `buildLocationSuggestions()`.

```
class SuggestionsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  _SuggestionsWidgetState createState() => _SuggestionsWidgetState();
}

class _SuggestionsWidgetState extends State<SuggestionsWidget> {
  final duration = Duration(milliseconds: 250);
  SuggestionsController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Suggestion>>(
      stream: controller.suggestions,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return buildLocationSuggestions(snapshot.data);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = SuggestionsController(duration);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(SuggestionsWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    controller.dispose();
    controller = SuggestionsController(duration);
  }
}
```

It's not clear from your example where the `query` string comes from, but to finish wiring this up, you would call `controller.query.add(newQuery)` and StreamBuilder handles the rest.

**Conclusion**

Since the API you're using yields Futures, it seems a little more straightforward to use that approach. The downside is the overhead of the Debouncer class and adding a Completer to tie it in to FutureBuilder.

The stream approach is popular, but includes a fair amount of overhead as well. Creating and disposing of the streams correctly can be tricky if you're not familiar.

Comment: Thanks @jacob once I am back from vacation I will give your solution a try and marker it correct if it works, generally it sounds right, now speaking about "query" it's a property set on the delegate from the flutter team who created the SearchPage widget, it reoresents the text that's currently in the TextField, which I consider as a bad design, instead of explicitly sending it along with methods that are invoked to get suggestions, they just decided to keep it on a class level, there are indeed many other ways than doing it this way.

Comment: Yeah I kinda overdid this one while avoiding other work. It really bugged me the best answer I found was to convert it to a stream. Anyway, cheers!

Comment: Thanks again @Jacob Phillips, Please update the answer to indicate that I have to recreate a completer every time the method completes, otherwise It throws an exception, even though I use Completer in Rx, I didn't associate it to that right away, it took me a while to understand what's going on.

Comment: Okay will do tomorrow. The package helps mitigate that issue since it recreates the completer internally. Its link shows an example, I just havent changed the answer.

Comment: Thank you Jacob for your explanation. May I ask you some further help?
I am trying to adapt your solution to `buildSuggestions` method in the `SearchDelegate` class using the "Future-based approach".
What I don't understand is how could the timer be reset every time the `buildSuggestions` method is invoked. Should the completer be a property of the `SearchDelegate` class?
But once the `Future` is completed the first time, does every call to `buildSuggestions` executes the API call without having to wait for the timer in `debouncer` to complete again?

Comment: @Luca Just use the `Debouncer` class from [`simple_observable`](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_observable)

Comment: @JacobPhillips how to call getAutocompleteSuggestions only for last value using Future-based approach? if I type a word from 4 letters, after last delay getAutocompleteSuggestions was called 4 times, not once.

Answer (score 8):

I Simply did it this way no library required:

```
void searchWithThrottle(String keyword, {int throttleTime}) {
    _timer?.cancel();
    if (keyword != previousKeyword && keyword.isNotEmpty) {
      previousKeyword = keyword;
      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: throttleTime ?? 350), (timer) {
        print("Going to search with keyword : $keyword");
        search(keyword);
        _timer.cancel();
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: But how to integrate this code with `Widget buildResults(BuildContext context)` or `Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple alternative to the other answer.

```
import 'package:debounce_throttle/debounce_throttle.dart';

final debouncer = Debouncer<String>(Duration(milliseconds: 250));

Future<List<Suggestion>> queryChanged(String query) async {
  debouncer.value = query;      
  return GooglePlaces.getInstance().getAutocompleteSuggestions(await debouncer.nextValue)
}

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Suggestion>>(
      future: queryChanged(query),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Suggestion>> suggestions) {
        if (!suggestions.hasData) {
          return Text('No results');
        }
        return buildLocationSuggestions(suggestions.data);
      },
    );
  }
```

That's roughly how you should be doing it I think.

Here are a couple of ideas for using a stream instead, using the debouncer.

```
void queryChanged(query) => debouncer.value = query;

Stream<List<Suggestion>> get suggestions async* {
   while (true)
   yield GooglePlaces.getInstance().getAutocompleteSuggestions(await debouncer.nexValue);
}

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Suggestion>>(
      stream: suggestions,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Suggestion>> suggestions) {
        if (!suggestions.hasData) {
          return Text('No results');
        }
        return buildLocationSuggestions(suggestions.data);
      },
    );
  }
```

Or with a StreamTransformer.

```
Stream<List<Suggestion>> get suggestions => 
  debouncer.values.transform(StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (value, sink) => sink.add(GooglePlaces.getInstance()
      .getAutocompleteSuggestions(value))));
```

Comment: This answer seems to be a bit outdated. Your simple_observable package no longer has a Debouncer class

Comment: yeah i moved it to a package named `debounce_throttle`

Comment: i tried to use your Future code but it still executes it more than once. shouldnt this be executed only once? e.g.  2 seconds. i type fast 3 numbers , it doesnt execute right away, only after 2 seconds have elapsed but still runs the function 3x.

Comment: That's odd, can you open an issue on the repo? https://pub.dev/packages/debounce_throttle

Comment: @JacobPhillips yes chitgoks is right it is getting called 3x

Comment: Using the package please let me know what can be possible solution

Comment: Changes in Dart may have broken the package. `Stream`s can be debounced and throttled. I'd look up how to do that. It's likely the `rxdart` package has it built in.

Comment: This code not working as I expected, because it's still call a request multiple times based on total user character typing

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting @Jacob Phillip's debounce_throttle package to work, as the code that worked for him back in 2018 no longer seems to work with the latest versions of Flutter / Dart. It waits for the debounce time to be reached but then executes all of the attempts at once after instead of just the last one.

I was able to get it working with some modifications. I would have posted this as a comment on his answer, but it's too long.

```
final _debouncer = Debouncer<String>(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), initialValue: '');
late String userQuery;

Future<Iterable<LocationModel>> onSearchChanged(TextEditingValue textEditingValue) async {
    // Debounce for half a second, so we don't make unnecessary api calls as the user types.
    _debouncer.value = userQuery = textEditingValue.text;
    await _debouncer.nextValue;
    if (textEditingValue.text != userQuery) {
      return const Iterable<LocationModel>.empty();
    }
    // Only retrieve location suggestions if the user typed at least 4 characters...
    if (textEditingValue.text.length < _userQueryMinSuggestionsLength) {
      return const Iterable<LocationModel>.empty();
    }

    // Get user's location.
    var position = await _locationService.getPosition();
    // Get location suggestions.
    var propertyMode = await _userSettingsService.propertyMode;
    try {
      _locationSuggestions = await _placesService.getLocationSuggestionsAsync(
          propertyMode, textEditingValue.text, position.latitude, position.longitude, LocationSearchType.property);
    } catch (e) {
      handleError(e, message: 'Error retrieving location suggestions');
    }
    notifyListeners();
    return _locationSuggestions ?? [];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Timer can be used to debounce search input.

```
  Timer debounce;

  void handleSearch(String value) {
    if (debounce != null) debounce.cancel();
    setState(() {
      debounce = Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        searchItems(value);
         //call api or other search functions here
      });
    });
  }
```

whenever a new input is added to the text box the function cancels previous timer and start a new one. The search function will be only initiated after 2 seconds of inactivity

Comment: But how to integrate this code with `Widget buildResults(BuildContext context)` or `Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the updated code for null safety in case anyone is looking for just copy paste. I know programmer can scroll two pages instead of just appending a '?' after the variables :)

```
class Debouncer<T> {
      Debouncer({required this.duration, required this.onValue});
      final Duration duration;
      void Function(T? value) onValue;
      T? _value;
      Timer? _timer;
      T? get value => _value;
      set value(T? val) {
        _value = val;
        _timer?.cancel();
        _timer = Timer(duration, () => onValue(_value));
      }
    }
```

Comment: you missed the '?' on: void Function(T value) onValue; So it becomes:  void Function(T? value) onValue; Tks BTW :)

Answer (score 0):

I added debounce logic within the API call method ... so I won't have to update every place and make logic centralized...

```
Timer? _debounceTimer; 

Future<void> searchAPICall(BuildContext context, String query) async {
    // Cancel the previous debounce timer if it exists to prevent extra calls 
    if (_debounceTimer != null && _debounceTimer!.isActive) {
      _debounceTimer!.cancel();
    }

    // Start a new debounce timer
    _debounceTimer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async { 
      //Make API call or do something
      
    });
  }
```

Dispose the timer when the object is disposed

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _debounceTimer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```